# What is the difference between 月々 and 毎月?

Tags: meaning, words, synonyms

I wanna ask you abou these synonym words. Here are the sentences.
彼は家賃を月々ちゃんと払う. (He pays his rent regularly every month)
彼は毎月積金している(He lays by some money every month)
What is the different between 月々 and 毎月? Both are has same meaning 'monthly; every month'. I read those sentences above and has no idea where the different is.

Comment: I sort of assume (and it could be way off) that 毎月 is used when setting a topic vs using it doing it at some frequency...

Answer (score 1):

「月々」と「毎月」とはほとんど同じですが、質問者の例を含めて次に挙げる例のように、使われ方に差があるような気がします。そして、これらの例は、相互に入れ替えても十分意味は通じますが、入れ替えると若干の不自然さを感じます。ただし、「自然さ/不自然さ」を余り気付かない、あるいは気にしない日本人も普通にいるだろうと思います。

【毎月】

- 毎月貯金をしている。
- 毎月第一月曜日に集金に来る。
- 給料は毎月第三金曜日に銀行に振り込まれる。

【月々】

- 家賃を月々ちゃんと払っている。
- 月謝を月々ちゃんと払っている。

「月々」は「月毎｛つきごと｝に」と置き換えても自然ですが、「毎月」を「月毎に」と置き換えると余り自然ではありません。この場合も、置き換えで生じる「自然さ/不自然さ」を余り気付かない、あるいは気にしない、更には差がないという日本人は普通にいるだろうと思います。

【毎日、毎年】

- 毎日お風呂に入る。
- 毎日犬を連れて散歩する。
- 毎年年賀状が来ていた友人から今年は来ない。どうしたのだろうか。
- 毎年のことだが、秋になると渡り鳥が来る。

【日々｛ひび｝、年々｛ねんねん｝】

- 日々成長する。
- 年々大きくなる。

---

## EDIT

次のような実際に使われている文（Ａ）を見つけました。
文（Ａ）の中の「毎年」と「年々」を入れ替えた文（Ｂ）は不自然な日本語に思えます。
このことから「毎年」と「年々」とは若干違うことが分かります。

> （Ａ）**毎年**調査を行っていますが、**年々**店舗の意識も上がり、ほとんどの店舗できちんとした規制が行われていました。
> （Ｂ）**年々**調査を行っていますが、**毎年**店舗の意識も上がり、ほとんどの店舗できちんとした規制が行われていました

Comment: So, from your sentences Ive my conclusion. 月々 is used for what we must do every month (have a responsibility nuance) and 毎月 used for what usually does based on what we like? Is that so?

Comment: @user25631: I think that your understanding is partly correct, but it couldn't always be said like that. Although I could show you the use cases inductively, I'm sorry to say that I cannot define the usage deductively.

Comment: @user25631: 「月々」の方が「毎月」より、一つ一つの「月 month」を丁寧｛ていねい｝に扱｛あつ｝っているように思います。私の辞書｛じしょ｝では「毎月」は " every month"、「月々」は "from month to month; month after month; month by month"と書かれています。また「月々」は「毎月毎月」とも言うとなっています。毎日と日々、毎年と年々についても後者の方が「一日」あるいは「一年」を丁寧に扱っているように思います。